# How to concornate string with method?

Tags: rest, web-services, c#-4.0, methods, javascript-objects

Have to pass method name dynamically in the method?

```
HttpResponseMessage messgeConnection = clientConnection.PostAsync(URLConnection, contentConnection).Result; // Dynamically I need to pass my method
    static string BasicIOCommunication(String Url,String Data, String AuthendicationHeader, string Content_Type)
    {
        string URLConnection = Url;
        string DATAConnection = Data;

        System.Net.Http.HttpClient clientConnection = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        clientConnection.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(URLConnection);

        clientConnection.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", AuthendicationHeader);
        clientConnection.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        System.Net.Http.HttpContent contentConnection = new StringContent(DATAConnection, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, Content_Type);

        var method = "PostAsync";

        HttpResponseMessage messgeConnection = clientConnection.PostAsync(URLConnection, contentConnection).Result; // Dynamically I need to pass my method

        //HttpResponseMessage messgeConnection = clientConnection.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, method);

        if (messgeConnection.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string resultConnection = messgeConnection.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return resultConnection;
        }

        return "False";
    }
```

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're trying to do. What method would you use *apart* from PostAsync? Please give us more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
  public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = 
             Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value");
        response.Content = new StringContent("javascriptmethodname");
        return response;
    }
```

---

or

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();    
response.Content ="javascriptmethodname";
```

you can write this where you are creating object of `HttpResponseMessage` in your code.

Comment: I have updated my code. Can you give some idea where should I add this code?

Comment: I'm using HttpClient Request.

Comment: @MonishaA - updated answer ...you need to put code at the palce you are creating HttpResponseMessage object

Comment: @MonishaA - you change will go here  HttpResponseMessage messgeConnection = clientConnection.PostAsync(URLConnection, contentConnection).Result; // Dynamically I need to pass my method